# How to convert VSD file to png type through java

Tags: java, png, converters, visio

I need to convert the Visio diagrams into png type files. Gone through the [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/diagram/index.html) API and tried sample conversion from [VsdxToPng](https://github.com/BBN-D/poi-visio/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xdgf/util/VsdxToPng.java). No luck with that and that too it was for vsdx to png conversion not vsd to png.
Please help me if have any Java API or sample code to converting from vsd to png type using Java.

Comment: You have come to a wrong place. Please ask a MVFQ

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/653092/Visio-Diagram-Conversion-PDF-HTML look a this

Comment: Could you describe any research you've done on this topic?

Comment: I have tried as like in this link https://github.com/BBN-D/poi-visio/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xdgf/util/VsdxToPng.java
Using the Apache POI https://poi.apache.org/diagram/index.html.

Comment: But It was for vsdx to png file type conversion and I did not find API for vsd to png.

Answer (score 1):

VSD is a proprietary binary format, not really publicly documented, and hard to parse. As for the libraries, I'm not aware of any open source library that can do that. You could try commercial ones like [Aspose.Diagrams](https://products.aspose.com/diagram/java)